# Why isn't my text file reading in Java Eclipse as a String?

Tags: java, text-files

I'm a beginner in Java Eclipse. I am trying to read a .txt file, and use the data as a String value. However, when I use an `if` statement, the condition is not registering the value as a String and is therefore not meeting any conditions and I am only getting the final `else`.

The purpose of my code is to read in a text file and determine the required value: i.e. if the line starts with "avg" , the program must display the average of the following numbers.

My .txt file contents is this:

min:1,2,3,4,5,6\n
max:1,2,3,4,5,6\n
avg:1,2,3,4,5,6

Here is a part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    //declare variables
    String line, operation;
    int min, max, sum, num;
    double avg;
    List<String> lineArray;
    String outputPath = "C:\\output.txt";       //these are not the actual file paths, i just didnt 
    String inputPath = "C:\\input.txt";         //want to give personal information.

    //try open file
    try {
        
        //create File instance  
        File text = new File (inputPath);   
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);                               

        //loop until end of text file
        while ( scnr.hasNextLine() ) {
                            
            line = scnr.nextLine();                  //read line from text file
            operation = line.substring(0,3);         //get operation from String data
            
            line = line.substring(4);                //get String value of numbers              
            lineArray = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));     //separate string into array elements

            //setup initial values
            sum = 0;
            min = Integer.parseInt(lineArray.get(0));     //convert to Int
            max = Integer.parseInt(lineArray.get(0));
            
            //loop through line array and determine min, sum and max of each
            for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.size(); i++ ) {
                
                num = Integer.parseInt(lineArray.get(i));
                sum += Integer.parseInt(lineArray.get(i));
                if (num > max)  max = num;
                if (num < max)  max = num;
                
            }
            
            avg = sum / lineArray.size();   
            
            //the IF condition statement that is not working                
            if (operation  == "min") {
                System.out.println(min);
            }
            
            else if (operation == "max") {
                System.out.println(max);
            }
            
            else if (operation == "avg") {
                System.out.println(avg);
            }
            
            else System.out.println("Error");
            
        }   //end of while loop
        
        scnr.close();                                                       //close scanner
        
    }   //end of try
    
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
    }
    
}   //end of "main" class
```

When I manually set operation as "min" or "max" or "avg" the program works as it should.

Comment: Step 1 is to not write catch blocks that literally swallow all information and silently keep running. If exceptions occur, you'd never know. The right move is to declare main as `throws Exception`. If that's not possible, the content of a catch block should be `throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);` unless you have an actual plan to deal with it (and logging it, or printing it, or swallowing it, is _not_ dealing with it). Once you've sorted that, also fix your string comparison (use `.equals`, not `==`), then rerun.

Comment: thank you, I will try that, appreciate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of operation  == "min" you should use operation.equals("min"). And so on for the other strings, you want to compare.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I really appreciate the help